# Accented characters in a hyperlink, and problems with opening a new window

Tags: hyperref, luatex, fontspec, unicode

With this MWE, I have different results depending on the pdfviewer on linux box :

**Evince** dosen't find the link because of the `é`, but opens a new window on a non-accented link

**Okular** finds the link but doesn't open either a new window or a new tab (the option in okular is set)

**Acrobat reader 9** doesn't find the link because of the `é`

**Acrobat reader XI** works fine

Is there a way to make it work with **evince** or **okular** ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmainfont{Erewhon}[
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    SlantedFont=*-RegularSlanted,
    BoldSlantedFont=*-BoldSlanted,
    ]

\setsansfont{texgyreheros}[
    Scale=MatchUppercase,% or MatchLowercase
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-regular,
    ItalicFont=*-italic,
    BoldFont=*-bold,
    BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
    ]

\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfnewwindow=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
        \href{run:Numération.pdf}{%
        \frame{\includegraphics{Numération}}}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Does it make a difference if you were to load the `graphicx` package instead of `graphics`? (I ask because I can't replicate the issue your facing, as I (unsurprisingly) don't have a file called `Numération.pdf` on my system.) Separately, do the issues go away if you rename `Numération.pdf` to `Numeration.pdf`, say?

Comment: No difference, I usually use graphicx package. It's a typo error. I'll correct this. Try with any accuentued name file, I have the same behavior with all of them.

Comment: Easy solution, don't use accents in fiilenames.  I can't test this myself (no Numération.pdf), but try `Num\\`eration.pdf`

Comment: I have alraidy tested that with no sucess in evince : Erreur lors de l'obtention des informations du fichier « /home/nico/Numérations_Anciennes/Num�ration.pdf » : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type. As you can see, the full path is correctly accentued but the name of the file is wrong.